# Is there any verse in the Quran which states that dancing is haram?

Tags: halal-haram, quran, behavior

Mostly people express their happiness in some form of actions (eg. by dancing, like at weddings or some sort of occasion).

My question is very simple: Is there any verse in the Quran which states that dancing is haram?

Also if a person wants to dance (even just for a competition) will it be considered as a huge sin?  Is dancing (even during some celebration/occasion) a sin in Islam? And if yes, why? Is it not okay to express happiness or joy through dancing?

Comment: Related: [Is dancing allowed in Islam?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/42902/is-dancing-allowed-in-islam)

Answer (score 1):

Dancing is influenced mostly by culture. I used to dance in my school days lifting arms up and down counting out loud "*one two three four*". There's no issue in that I reckon.

But what's [discouraged](http://corpus.quran.com/translation.jsp?chapter=53&verse=61) is dance as a form of entertainment [e.g.](https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=lFMdWNHqF_Lx8AfLxoXICA#safe=active&q=robot%20dance). They may create fantasies and desires in people.

Further worse and that which is strictly not allowed is anything ranging from  romantic songs of Bollywood to western music and dances in it and everything above that.

Answer (score 1):

You can freely dance with your wife. There may be no exact rule obviously to not dance, but we can defer the meaning from behaviours of Prophet Muhammad(s.a.v.). He even always avoids to handshake with a girl except close relations (his wifes, daughters, etc.) So, you cannot dance with a strange girl. By the way, to verify my point of view, google is your best friend.

> It was narrated that Ma’qil ibn Yassaar said: the Messenger of Allaah
>   (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “For one of you to
>   be stabbed in the head with an iron needle is better for him than that
>   he should touch a woman who is not permissible for him.”
>
> Narrated by al-Tabaraani in al-Kabeer, 486. Shaykh al-Albaani said
>   in Saheeh al-Jaami’, 5045, that this hadeeth is saheeh.

Comment: Touch in this hadith has the same meaning as touch when Maryam said; "She said, "How can I have a boy while no man has touched me" ... I.e touch in this hadith stands for sex.

Comment: @Kilise why do you think that some stranger man touched maryam?! and why do you think that maryam and muhammad lied?

Comment: @qdinar read again..

Comment: @Kilise i think it does not stand for sex because it would be lie and lie is prohibited

Comment: @qdinar what has lie to do with this? please read carefully.  also read my answer in the question "what does touch mean in this Hadith?"

Comment: https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/39935/what-is-meant-by-touch-in-this-hadith/39936#39936

Answer (score 1):

I'll investigate this question: **Is there any verse in the Quran which states that dancing is haram?**

*Conclusion*: Multiple fatawa on the topic failed to cite Qur'an ayat declaring dancing haram, and some fatawa even declare modest dancing to be halal.  From this, we can surmise that no verse of the Qur'an declares dancing haram.

The most relevant Qur'an ayah mentioned in these fatawa is:

> And of the people is he who buys the amusement of speech to mislead [others] from the way of Allah without knowledge and who takes it in ridicule. Those will have a humiliating punishment. -- [Qur'an 31:6](https://quran.com/31/6)

I found this quoted three times.  [Islam Awakened](http://islamawakened.com/quran/31/6/) gives others translations.  No translation directly mentions dancing.

---

Islam Q&A has several fatawa on the topic ([1](https://islamqa.info/en/5000); [2](https://islamqa.info/en/180705); [3](https://islamqa.info/en/9290); [4](https://islamqa.info/en/143924); [5](https://islamqa.info/en/197384); [6](https://islamqa.info/en/100602)). [This](https://islamqa.info/en/9290) one even mentions a scholar who writes "Dancing is makrooh in principle".

IslamWeb also has fatawa on the topic ([1](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=348382); [2](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=81604); [3](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=88445); [4](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=84246)).  [This fatwa](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=348382) even writes: "there is nothing wrong for a young girl who is not desired for sexual intercourse to dance in front of men provided that she does not dance in a way that causes temptation".

[Darul Ifta Birmingham](http://daruliftabirmingham.co.uk/ruling-on-dancing/) writes: "Dancing is haraam by the consensus of all the Fuqahaa (Jurists)", not quoting the Qur'an.

Other fatawa are: Qibla.com (sourced from IslamQA.org [1](http://islamqa.org/shafii/qibla-shafii/34214); [2](http://islamqa.org/shafii/qibla-shafii/33989)); [MuftiSays](http://www.muftisays.com/qa/question/3675/dancing.html); [Darul Ifta Deoband](http://www.darulifta-deoband.com/home/en/Halal--Haram/43933); [SeekersHub](http://seekershub.org/ans-blog/2013/04/07/dancing-in-private-for-one%E2%80%99s-spouse/).