# Is dancing allowed in Islam?

Tags: halal-haram, behavior

Is dancing allowed in Islam?

The first part of my question is in regards to dancing in public. I am pretty sure it is not permissible, but is there any evidence of reasoning to support this view?

Secondly, I'd like to ask about dancing in private. Like, is dancing allowed when you are alone, or with people of your gender. This way, there will be no non-mahram around. Additionally, would it be permissible to dance in front/with mahram or the females you are mahram to? Like husband-wife or sister-brother?

Q: Is there any evidence to support the view that dancing is not permissible in public?
   Is dancing permissible in private where you are alone, with people your gender, or with a mahram/female you are mahram to?

Answer (score 4):

Performing dance ( رقص )  is haram when it involves other haram actions like intoxication, uncovering of the 'awrah, vulgarity etc.

There is difference among the madhabs on the ruling on dancing  which is free from the above. The position of the majority is that it is makruh. Their evidence includes:

- It comes under the meaning of the following verse:

  > ولا تمش في الأرض مرحا
  >
  > And do not walk upon the earth exultantly.
  >
  > <sup>— [Quran 17:37](http://quran.com/17/37)</sup>

  > استدل العلماء بهذه الآية على ذم الرقص وتعاطيه
  >
  > The Ulema have used this verse as evidence for the condemnation of dancing.
  >
  > <sup>— [Tafsir al-Qurtubi](http://quran.ksu.edu.sa/tafseer/qortobi/sura17-aya38.html#qortobi)</sup>
- It is a form of *Lahw* ( لهو ) -  a useless pastime:

  > كل ما يلهو به الرجل المسلم باطل إلا رميه بقوسه وتأديبه فرسه وملاعبته أهله
  >
  > All idle pastimes that the Muslim man engages in are falsehood, except for his shooting of his bow, his training of his horse, and his playing with his wife.
  >
  > <sup>— [Jami at-Tirmidhi](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/22/19)</sup>
- It is agreed upon by the jurists that it is unbecoming of a respectable or honorable person, as the testimony is not accepted of a person who engages in it regularly.

Reference: https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/134103/

Comment: "Playing with his wife" Can't dancing pass as a form of couple's play?

Answer (score 0):

Assalamu Alaikum,

Dancing by itself is not impermissible as there is not a single hadith prohibiting it. But you should follow some rules regarding dance as Allah says: And who observe limits set by Allah. [9:112]

1) You should not dance if there is an opposite gender person present even if it is mahram relative.

2) Your dance must not contain any immoral/immodest move/moves.

These above rules are according to Quran. As Allah says in many verses that you must not create Fitnah (i.e. Noxiousness). And also don't promote sinful activities or just to maintain Haya (i.e. Modesty). About which Prophet Muhammad (peace be upon him) said:

“every religion has a (distinct) characteristic and the characteristic of islam is modesty.” [ibn Maajah]

And

Apostle of Allah (peace be upon him) said: “Faith is composed of seventy and odd branches of which the highest is belief in la ilaha il-lalah [i.e., the testimony of divine oneness] and the lowest is the removal of a hindrance from the road, and the sense of modesty is an important branch of faith.” [Bukhari and Muslim]

Thank you.