# Is twerking halal or haram in Islam?

Tags: nikah, sex

Salam

I was only asking because of the society we live in

Thank you

Comment: Assalamualaikum warahmatullahi wabarakatuhu, welcome to Islam stack exchange, your question is really not understand please take a time to read [ask] for more information or even [Tour] Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is dancing allowed in Islam?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/42902/is-dancing-allowed-in-islam)

Answer (score -1):

It is it not haram if you are doing it privately with your husband.